# How do I obtain a weighted frequency table with proportions?

Tags: r, weighted, frequency-table

I'm working on a dataset that includes a post-stratification weight, and I am looking for a way to get more info about specific variables after they have been weighted, but I am struggling.

Here's a sample dataframe:

```
a <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, NA, NA)
wght <- c(0.8, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 1.1, 1, 0.8)
df <- data.frame(a, wght)
```

Column a contains the coded responses to a question (say `agree`/`neutral`/`disagree`), and `wght` contains the weight. I found a way to display the weighted number of observations:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% dplyr::count(a, wt=wght)
```

I would now like to get the info on this distribution that I could get with `freq` from the `descr` package (especially percentage and valid percentage). I tried various things, such as the following, but it produces a strange frequency table.

```
dfwt <- df %>% count(a, wt=wght)
freq(dfwt$a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freq` from `{descr}` is used as following:

```r
df$a <- factor(df$a, levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("agree", "neutral", "disagree"))

descr::freq(df$a, df$wght, plot = FALSE)

# df$a 
#          Frequency Percent Valid Percent
# agree          3.1   27.68         32.98
# neutral        2.7   24.11         28.72
# disagree       3.6   32.14         38.30
# NA's           1.8   16.07              
# Total         11.2  100.00        100.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xtabs` and convert `as.data.frame` so you don't need to load packages. Then just `cbind` the `proportions`. Valid percentages are calculated without the `NA`s.

```
tbl <- as.data.frame(xtabs(wght ~ a, df, addNA=TRUE))

cbind(tbl, perc=proportions(tbl$Freq)*100, valid_perc=c(proportions(na.omit(tbl)$Freq), NA)*100)
#      a Freq     perc valid_perc
# 1    1  3.1 27.67857   32.97872
# 2    2  2.7 24.10714   28.72340
# 3    3  3.6 32.14286   38.29787
# 4 <NA>  1.8 16.07143         NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, NA, NA), wght = c(0.8, 
0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 1.1, 1, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```